# undefined method `map' for #<Class:0x007f96ac17c948>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grouped-collection-select

I am using `grouped_collection_select` and do not understand why I get the error: `undefined method 'map' for   Class`

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :tournament %><br>
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :tournament_id, Tour, :tournaments, :event,:id, :event%></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [documentation for grouped_collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-grouped_collection_select).

The second argument should be a collection, and you are passing it what looks like a Tour object.

The underlying code will try and call map on the collection, to modify it's content. The Tour object does not have a map method.

Try this:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :tournament_id, Tour.all, :tournaments, :event,:id, :event%></div>
```